# Snakemake: Manually creating a wildcard from a string

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, wildcard, snakemake

Suppose I have two strings, a template and target string.

Template string: `"param1~{wildcard1}/param2~{wildcard2}_param3~{wildcard3}"`

Target string: `"param1~1.1/param2~a_b_c_param3~345"`

I would like to create a function that takes in a template string and target string as arguments. The function returns a wildcard object (or dictionary, or some data structure that can hold key-value pairs) where the key is the wildcard name (i.e wildcard1) and the value is the value of the wildcard in the target string (i.e 1.1)

Here's a little example:

```py
def extract_wildcards(template, target):
    ... (implementation) ...
    return wildcards
```

Usage:

```py
wildcards = extract_wildcards("param1~{wildcard1}/param2~{wildcard2}_param3~{wildcard3}",
                              "param1~1.1/param2~a_b_c_param3~345")
print(wildcards.wildcard1)
>"1.1"
print(wildcards.wildcard2)
>"a_b_c"
print(wildcards.wildcard3)
>"345"
```

Note that type casting is not necessary! All the values should strings. Wildcard names in the template will always be surrounded by `{}`. For the target string, you can assume that there is always only 1 way to extract wildcard values (no ambiguity in terms of what the each wildcard can be)

Answer (score 3):

There is a useful library for this, [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/), which can be installed via `pip`:

```sh
pip install parse
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```py
template = "param1~{wildcard1}/param2~{wildcard2}_param3~{wildcard3}"
target = "param1~1.1/param2~a_b_c_param3~345"

# pip install parse
from parse import parse

wildcards = parse(template, target).named
print(wildcards)
# {'wildcard1': '1.1', 'wildcard2': 'a_b_c', 'wildcard3': '345'}
```

In an earlier version of this answer I thought this is what `snakemake` uses internally, but that was wrong. In fact, there is another `parse` function defined [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/b0b206c4c34616093d7655789487f923b51e365b/snakemake/parser.py#L1217), which can result in a naming conflict (if the external `parse` library is used). One way to avoid that problem is to import the external module with an alias, e.g. `parse_external`:

```py
from parse import parse as parse_external
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this is isn't too related, it doesn't appear that it comes with snakemake. After installing it, I get this error: `parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'overwrite_shellcmd'`. This error appears in a completely different location from where I used parse(). It was found in an `include: rules/preproc.smk` statement in the Snakefile. This `preproc.smk` file contains the function that calls my `parse()`. Do you happen to know why that error exists?

Comment: Interesting, there is a function that `snakemake` defines with the same name [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/b0b206c4c34616093d7655789487f923b51e365b/snakemake/parser.py#L1217). Which means that my post is not accurate, I will update it now.

Answer (score 2):

This works for your example. The idea is to turn the snakemake string into a regex pattern and extract the matches. There might be some weirdness if the filename ends up producing unexpected regex patterns so keep that in mind.

```
import re

def extract_wildcards(template, target):
    names = re.findall("{[^{]*}", template)
    names = [name.strip("{}") for name in names]
    
    q = re.sub("{[^{]*}", "(.*)", template)
    matches = re.search(q, target)

    wildcards = dict()
    for i,name in enumerate(names):
        wildcards[name] = matches.group(i+1)
    return wildcards
```

example:

```
template="param1~{wildcard1}/param2~{wildcard2}_param3~{wildcard3}"
target="param1~1.1/param2~a_b_c_param3~345"
print(extract_wildcards(template, target))
  > {'wildcard1': '1.1', 'wildcard2': 'a_b_c', 'wildcard3': '345'}
```

I'm not sure what the goal of doing this is but it doesn't feel like a very "snakmake"-esqe solution. Have you considered trying an input function? https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=function#input-functions
This type of function gets passed the wildcards automatically

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible for the implementation to take in any name for a wildcard (i.e not just wildcard1, wildcard2, etc.)?

Comment: I am deviating a little from the snakemake way of doing things, and it is because I'm trying to replicate the `Paramspace.instance` method in snakemake, but in such a way that it fits my use-case.

Comment: I've updated the code to extract the wildcard name from the template.